# Run lightning-charge on c-lightning regtest

Tags: lightning-network, regtest, lightning-network-daemon, core-lightning, lightning-nodes

I'm trying to run lighting-charge (https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning-charge) on top of one of my 2 lightning (https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning) instances. I am running 2 nodes using the script here: `lightning/contrib/startup_regtest.sh`. This file will start a bitcoin instance as well as 2 lightning nodes (`/tmp/l1-regtest`, `/tmp/l2-regtest`)

I then tried to run lightning-charge with:

```
$ NETWORK=regtest charged --api-token super_secret_1 --ln-path ~/.lightning --db-path ~/charge1.db --port 9112
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Lightning client connection error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ~/.lightning
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '~/.lightning' }
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ~/.lightning
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
```

I've also tried running it with `ln-path` set to `/tmp/l1-regtest/`

with `ps aux` I can see lightning is running with this command:

```
~/git/lightning/lightningd/lightningd --lightning-dir=/tmp/l1-regtest
and
~/git/lightning/lightningd/lightningd --lightning-dir=/tmp/l2-regtest
```

Does anyone know how to get `lightning-charge` to connect to my regtest lightning node?

There are instructions on how to do this in docker in the readme file (https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning-charge/blob/master/README.md), but it doesn't seem to work outside of docker.

Comment: Does lightning charge connect via a port to lightning? I just realized that the regtest lightning doesn't use the default port 9735 but actually uses 6060 and 9090

Comment: I guess I could just run it on docker and mount the lightning and Bitcoin dirs. It does explain how to do that in the readme. It's pretty complicated though so I was hoping to avoid using docker. I'll report back after I've tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in your call of `charged` there you are passing the argument `--ln-path ~/.lightning` assuming that you run lightning in your home directory thus you have to set `ln-path` to `/tmp/l1-regtest/`.

Now you say that this also did not work. So before I give you a solution let me explain what is actually going on. `charged` talkes to `lightningd` via an rpc-interface on an UNIX Domain socket. In older versions of `lightningd` there was a file called `lightning-rpc` in the folder that you specified as `lightning-dir` however `lightningd` has switched its API recently to to have subdirectories in `lightning-dir` for mainnet, testnet and regtest. (the reason was that in particular in the default directory people wanted to have different configs for mainnet, testnet and regtest)

Thus I assume that you will find `lightning-rpc` when you do `ls /tmp/l1-regtest/regtest` which means that you should pass the `tmp/l1-regtest/regtest` in `--ln-path` when you call `charged`. If that is not the case I would have to see another error message.

Comment: It works! thank you and thanks for making all those yt videos!